# How to normalize an eigenvector when it has $\sqrt{i}$ as an entry?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, inner-products, orthonormal

If $V=\mathbb{C}^2$ and $T(a,b)=(2a+ib,a+2b)$ I found
 $$[T]_\beta=\begin{bmatrix}2 & i  \\ 1 & 2\end{bmatrix}$$ hence the eigenvalues are $2+\sqrt{i},2-\sqrt{i}$.

So using this, eigenvectors are $(\sqrt{i},1);(-\sqrt{i},1)$. 
Now to find orthonormal basis we need to use Gram-Schmidt and then normalize the vector. But my doubt is how to take norm of $(\sqrt{i},1)$? 
What will be conjugate of $\sqrt{i}$? And is my method correct?

This question is from book Linear algebra by Steven Friedberg

Comment: This question is from book  Linear algebra by Steven Friedberg

Comment: The norm is square root of the sum of absolute values squared. The absolute value of $i$ is $1$, so the absolute value of $\sqrt{i}$ is $\sqrt{1}$, which is also $1$.

Comment: The notation $\sqrt x$ is usually avoided when $x$ is not a real number. Generally you speak of a square root, not the square root ,of $x$ for non-real $x$.

Comment: @user254665. The notation $\sqrt x$ is generally avoided for good reasons, when $x$ is not a **positive** real number.

Comment: Please never use notations like $\sqrt{-1}$ or $\sqrt{\mathrm i}$. This generates confusion. For instance, it not true anymore that $\sqrt{xy}=\sqrt{x}\sqrt{y}$ ! (example of misuse of this rule : $1=\sqrt{1}=\sqrt{(-1)(-1)}=\sqrt{-1}\sqrt{-1}=-1$).  The notation $\sqrt{\mathrm i}$ is, likewise, mathematically ill-defined.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but I tried doing it like $z \bar z = |z|^2$, so the norm comes out to be $|\sqrt{\Bbb i}| ^2 =1$.

Hence, $\langle (\sqrt{\Bbb i}, 1), (\sqrt{\Bbb i}, 1)\rangle = 2$.

Comment: Which is correct although I never write $\sqrt i$

Answer (score 1):

(1)For any complex number $x$ we have  $x=r(\cos A+i\sin A)$ with $r\geq 0$ and real number $A$.And $|x|=r.$ For $x\neq 0$ the complex square roots of $ x$ are  $r^{1/2}(\cos A/2+i\sin A/2)$ and $r^{1/2}(\cos (A/2+\pi)+i\sin (A/2+\pi))$.  Observe that if $y^2=x$ then $|y|=|x|^{1/2}.$ (2) The conjugate of $r(\cos A+i\sin A)$ for real $r,A$ is $r(\cos A-i\sin A)$.